How to extract arguments from a function and group them by type, int, string or array
Is there a way to extract function argument and group them by type: int, string or array from a substring with regex in PHP?
I need to find all the arguments of type string and prefix them with the dollar sign.
So far I have tried this pattern but I have not been able to solve the problem:
$re = '/(?<func>\w+)\((?<arg>.\w+|\d+)|(?<arr>\[[^][]*])\)/';
$str = '
{{ labels(1, ["Jonh", "Doe"]) }}
{{ unescape(one, two, three) }}
{{ trans("welcome", ["Jane", "Doe"]) }}
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);

// Output
array (
    0 => array (
        0 => 'unescape(one',
        'func' => 'unescape',
        1 => 'unescape',
        'arg' => 'one',
        2 => 'one',
    ),
    1 => array (
        0 => 'labels(1',
        'func' => 'labels',
        1 => 'labels',
        'arg' => '1',
        2 => '1',
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => '["Jane", "Doe"])',
        'func' => '',
        1 => '',
        'arg' => '',
        2 => '',
        'arr' => '["Jane", "Doe"]',
        3 => '["Jane", "Doe"]',
    ),
)

What I need
array (
    0 => array (
            0 => 'escape(one, two, three)',
            'func' => 'unescape',
            'arg' => 'one', 'two', 'three',
            'str' => 'one', 'two', 'three'
        ),
    1 =>  array (
        0 => 'labels(1, "id", ["Jonh", "Doe"])',
        'func' => 'labels',
        'arg' => '1', 'id', ["Jonh", "Doe"],
        'int' => 1,
        'str' => 'id',
        'arr' => ["John", "Doe"]
    ),
    2 => array (
        0 => 'trans("welcome", ["Jane", "Doe"])',
        'func' => 'trans',
        'arg' => '"welcome", ["Jane", "Doe"]',
        'str' => 'welcome',
        'arr' => '["Jane", "Doe"]'
    ),
)

Thanks in advance.

"Is there a way to extract function argument" - Before going down a regex path, is there a specific language associated with this "function"? For instance, if this is PHP could you use reflection: https://3v4l.org/1tmon#v8.3.9. Or, are you parsing something (maybe akin to documentation), so you are really just in a string-only land.
